# Analysing spatio-temporal patterns using a GAM

Tags: r, gam, temporal

I am trying to analyse the spatio-temporal risk from disease using the following model;

```
mod2 = gam(TB ~ offset(log(Population)) + 
       s(Indigenous, k = 10, bs = "cr") + 
       s(Urbanisation, k = 10, bs = "cr") +
       s(Density, k = 10, bs = "cr") + Poverty + 
       s(Poor_Sanitation, k = 10, bs = "cr") + 
       Unemployment + Timeliness + Year + 
              Region + s(lon, lat), 
              data = TBdata, 
              family = nb(link = 'log'))
```

My issue is that I also want to analyze the difference is years (2012-2014) which i am not confident that my model does at the moment. How would I be able to do this? I've tried using 'Years' in an interaction with 'Population' as it makes some sort of sense but wasn't able to do this successfully.

Data if needed;

```
TBdata
# A tibble: 1,671 × 14
Indigenous Illiteracy Urbanisation Density Poverty Poor_Sanitation Unemployment Timeliness  Year    TB Population Region   lon    lat
<dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl> <int> <int>      <int>  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      0.335       6.35         84.1   0.714    31.3            15.3         5.41       59.2  2012   323     559543  11001 -60.7 -12.1 
 2      6.45        8.49         71.4   0.743    48.6            29.4         5.92       58.1  2012    15      73193  11002 -64.0  -9.43
```

Added information;

After editing my model i am now trying to plot my predictions.

I have used the current code which produces the following plot, although I think i might be missing my predictions so im just currently plotting the smooth function;

```
mod2 = gam(TB ~ offset(log(Population)) + s(Indigenous, k = 10, bs = "cr") + s(Urbanisation, k = 10, bs = "cr") +
              s(Density, k = 10, bs = "cr") + Poverty + s(Poor_Sanitation, k = 10, bs = "cr") + Unemployment + Timeliness +
              as.factor(Year) + Region + s(lon, lat), 
              data = TBdata, 
              family = nb(link = 'log'))
```

model summary

[image]

```
#plot
plot(mod2, contour.col = 'white', too.far = 0.10, scheme = 2, rug = T)
```

[image]

Although i think this shows the spatial trends I now need this for the different years, so i think what i want is a plot showing my predictions for each of the years (2012, 2013 and 2014)

Comment: Year must be set as a `factor`.

Comment: Perfect. Do you know how to add this to my plot? plot(nb_mod_cr2, contour.col = 'white', too.far = 0.10, scheme = 2, rug = T)

Comment: if you include `factor(Year)` in your formula, then the output of your model should include differences between years (by default, between the first year and subsequent years)

Comment: @BenBolker I though that should be the case, however im still just getting a single plot when plotting my model (model summary is fine)

Comment: You need to add a little detail to your statement that you want to "analyze the difference". Do you want to draw plots of predictions? Test the null hypothesis that there are no differences between years? Can you add some information from the model summary to your question?

Comment: @BenBolker ah yeh just realised that was a bit vague. Yeh I wish to draw plots of my model predictions. I'll add some info to the  question

Comment: Question is much improved (and you got a good answer).  Could you please edit your question to include the model summary info as **text** (probably code-formatted) rather than as an image/screenshot? (Images are unsearchable and inaccessible to people using screen readers.)

Answer (score 1):

When you `plot()` your model, you are just visualising the estimated smooth functions. As you only have a single spatial smooth, you get a single plot. There's no interaction between `factor(Year)` and `s(lon,lat)`.

Do yourself a favour and either convert `Year` to a factor in the data or create a new variable `fYear` that is `factor(Year)`. I'm going to assume you did the former in the below

If you want an interaction you need to use something like this `Year + s(lon, lat, by = Year)` in your model.

Then you'll get `nlevels(factor(Year))` spatial smooths when you `plot()` your GAM.

But even then those aren't **predictions**; you'll notice that the scale is centred about 0 (the grand mean of the data in the reference year in this case). To get plots of **predictions** you either need to use `predict()` with `newdata` set to a data frame containing all the combinations of the predictors you want to predict for/at, or use `vis.gam()`. For the latter you'll want:

```r
layout(matrix(c(1:3), nrow = 1))
vis.gam(mod2, view = c("lon", "lat"), cond = list(Year = "2012"),
        plot.type = "contour")
vis.gam(mod2, view = c("lon", "lat"), cond = list(Year = "2013"), 
        plot.type = "contour")
vis.gam(mod2, view = c("lon", "lat"), cond = list(Year = "2014"), 
        plot.type = "contour")
layout(1)
```

anything that you don't include in the list passed to `cond` will use a value that is either the observation closest to the median of the each respective continuous covariate or the modal level for factor variables.